# Python HTTP request, logged in but not quite

Tags: python, http

```
import requests
import random

with requests.Session() as c:
    url = 'https://www.example.com/ajax/logon.php?t=login'
    USERNAME = 'login'
    PASSWORD = 'password'

    AGENT = {'User-Agent': 'Its me',}
    c.get(url)
    tokens = c.cookies
    login_data = (('l',USERNAME), ('ph' , PASSWORD)) 
    c.post(url, data = login_data, headers=AGENT)
url2 = 'http://second.example.com/engine'
go_data = (('t','init'), ('value' , str(random.random())), ('id' , '6959025'))
page = c.get(url2, params = go_data, headers=AGENT)
print(page.text)
```

Am I doing everything allright? Because it's says that I am not logged in, also in Wireshark there's no POST request.
I am positive that this post is working because it logoffs me from my account.

Comment: you should do c.post instead of get. Also I think `go_data` should be a map and not  of type tuple. More about Session.post: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Session.post

Comment: That wasn't the problem, still doesn't work.

Comment: ah, one more thing. Is the indentation in your example wrong or are the last four lines meant to be outside of the `with requests...` block?

Comment: what you also could try: print the result of `c.post(url, data = login_data...)`. Do you get some kind of error message from the server?

Comment: The code is outside just because of pasting.
The result of c.post is Response <200>

Comment: what is the message from the server: content, status code? can you paste a server side stack trace maybe?